# What's the verb for swinging the skipping rope so that people can skip over it?

Tags: word-request

What's the verb for swinging the skipping rope so that people can skip over it? For example: "They were ___ the skipping rope so that their sisters could skip over it." I am not sure, but swinging is too general, because it doesn't imply a rotating motion.

Comment: Do you mean they were *jumping over* the skipping rope?

Comment: I think the OP is asking what the people _holding_ the rope do. I would say they were _turning_ it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was asking, but I never heard "turning" being used in this way.

Comment: Thinking back to my childhood, we called this "turning" the rope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term used in competitive contexts seems to be "turning":

> In competitive Double Dutch, there are two types of teams–a single team with three members (two turners, one jumper)

https://www.sportsrec.com/rules-doubledutch-jumping-5305285.html

> the second jumper exits the ropes, takes the ropes from the third team member (who has not
> yet jumped), and becomes the turner

https://www.worldjumprope.org/wp-content/uploads/2018-WJRF-Competition-Rule-Book.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Swinging is fine. If you need to say it was *not* just going from side to side you could use spinning the skipping rope.  But "holding" is probably enough in context

> Jak and Maz were holding the skipping rope while Katie skipped. A line of children waited in line for their turn in the middle. Jak spun the rope faster until it caught Katie, and she glared at him...